# operator vs () parenthesis in JAVA

Tags: operators, variable-assignment, operator-precedence, parentheses, associativity

```
int a=5;
a+=5+(++a)+(a++);
```

Now the  output should be 24 because first the parenthesis will be executed and if this is so then  it will be a=a+5+(++a)+(a++)=>a= 7 + 5 + 6 + 6  but the output  coming is 22, Why so??

I tried and searched but no where found the correct reason for the output to be 22.